# How can I run multiple filter based pubsub subscriptions in parallel?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, subscription

Problem statement : I have 2 programs to run in parallel which are triggered by pubsub messages.

My solution: I have a pubsub topic created which has 2 subscriptions which can filter msg based on attributes.name. Now I want to continuously listen to and read these subscriptions in parallel and trigger another program based on the filter.

How can I go about solving this? Can I create a flask webservice which can run these listeners in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consume the same message as the other program, you have to create a new subscription (with the correct filter). Indeed, the message are duplicated in parallel in each subscription.

If you want to scale out and to process the same subscription faster with another program, you can plug a new subscriber to that subscription (work only with pull subscription). The messages are dispatched between all the subscribers.